# Comma seperation only working on first 2 foreach items?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I've created a function to display the **taxonomies** of a Custom Post Type in WordPress, however I'm sure the problem's to do with something in the PHP:

```
function portfolio_tax($x) {
    $terms = get_terms($x);
    $count = count($terms);
    $commaCheck = 0;
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name;
        if(!$commaCheck >= $count){echo ', ';}
        $commaCheck++;
    }
}
```

I then use `<?php portfolio_tax('category');?>` (replacing *category* with *tag* in 2 different places, on the same page) to display them on a portfolio detail page.

All seems to be working fine with max. 2 items, but if there are any more, `,` stops displaying, like this:

> **Tags**
>
> Beach, HelloMacro

(When there should be a space between *Hello* & *Macro*)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of your statement. You checks firstly for !$commaCheck, what is defaultly true, because $commaCheck is 0, but then you ascend it. So it will be false.

Remove the ! before $commaCheck or put it in a () so like this: `!($commaCheck >= $count)`
(I dont know which logic do you need. With "!" or without.

Comment: Cheers, it was the missing `( )` around `$commaCheck >= $count` that I needed, completely missed them :-)

Comment: Because of a hurry. In future dont forget :P

Comment: Damn, I'm getting a `, ` after every item now, it's not only displaying when the condition is false, any ideas?

Comment: Try with $count -1 in statement

Answer (score 1):

Create a map of term names. You can then pop the last element off the end, join the rest up with a comma and concatenate the popped element back on:

```
function portfolio_tax($x) {
    $term_names = array_map(function($t){
        return $t -> name;
    }, get_terms($x));

    $last = array_pop($term_names);
    echo implode(',', $term_names) . ' ' . $last;
}
```

Comment: Will bare this in mind for the future, however gonna go with Tamás' answer as it's what I was missing!

Answer (score 0):

if($commaCheck >= $count){echo ', ';} try this by removing "!"

Comment: Thanks but need with `!`, Tamás has _correct_ answer

Answer (score 0):

Another (simpler) approach would be to echo the comma before every $term (exept the first one) instead of afterwards. In that case you would only need one counter-variable instead of two, to check if it is the first element.

```
function portfolio_tax($x) {
    $terms = get_terms($x);
    $commaCheck = 0;
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        if($commaCheck != 0){echo ', ';}
        echo $term->name;
        $commaCheck++;
    }
}
```